# "from either" vs "either from"

Tags: grammar

*The fat content of many processed foods is not clearly evident **from either** the appearance of the food, its feel and taste, or from the packaging and shape of the item.*

Is it possible for me to change the order of the words from *from either* to *either from* in this context?

Comment: I don't see why not. You could be criticised, though,  for using "either" with a three-member set.

Comment: @BillJ I assumed it'd be one set - appearance/feel/taste vs another - packaging/shape, but I agree it is a bit awkward.

Comment: No, the coordination consists of a three-member set: "the appearance of the food", "its feel and taste", and "the packaging of the item".

Comment: If you use ***from either**,* then you shouldn’t repeat “from” in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The grammatical structure you are using is *either A or B*. The phrases A and B both start with *from*, which you can extract and put in front of the phrase, so that you have two options:

1. *either from A or from B*
2. *from either A or B*

In your example, it is actually *from either A or from B*, but the second *from* seems redundant to me, as it would be option 2 above.

So in effect I would say that your proposed change makes the sentence more logical.

A counter argument is that having *from either* avoids a [garden path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden_path_sentence) interpretation of the sentence, where *either* is read as meaning *as well*; and then the *from* invalidates that interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

May I horn in in the debate? As a French native, I feel that *either from* sounds more pleasant to hear. But it's only my opinion :-)

Comment: What difficulty do you see in comparing "either from" and "from either", please?

They are very different, but that difference should present no difficulty.

Broadly, you use "either from" to explain that something comes from a choice of two sources, and "from either" to explain that the same thing might come from either source.

Comment: I agree to delete my answer if that's what jimm101 means. But I notice that the most explicit answer — **either from A or B** (limited to 2 alternatives) vs **from either A or B or C or D … or Z** was given AFTER my comment, which might mean that **some clarifications ARE useful**. So, if I delete my answer, this piece of knowledge will be lost, too.